# SQL injection Attack

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

How do i secure my site to SQL injection attacks? Im using PHP and mysql. Do i have to alter my mysql Query?

For example, i have one query like this:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];// im getting the Q value from the other form,from drop down box[displaying data using Ajax
$a1=$_POST['hosteladmissionno'];
$a2=$_POST['student_name'];
$a3=$_POST['semester'];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("hostel", $con);

$a1="SELECT  hosteladmissionno,student_name,semester FROM registration 
WHERE mess_type ".$q."' AND  status_flag=1";

$result = mysql_query($a1);

if ($result === false) {

    die(mysql_error());
}
echo "<table border='1' width=80%>
<tr>
 <th width=5%> S.No</th>
<th width=10%>H.Admin No</th>
<th width=10%>Student Name</th>
<th width=5%>No of Days</th>
</tr>";
 $i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $i=$i+1;
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td  align=center>" .$i."</td>";
  echo "<td size=10 align=center>" . $row['hosteladmissionno'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td size=35  align=center>" . $row['student_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td  align=center>  <input type='text' name='days' size=2> </td> ";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Do i have to include any alteration in my query to avoid Injection attacks? Any suggestion would be helpful.Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query appears (EDIT: appeared, in the first version of the query) to be entirely static - i.e. it doesn't use any user-supplied data. In that case, there's no risk of SQL injection.

SQL injection attacks involve taking user input and including that directly in a SQL query, instead of the preferred method of using a parameterized SQL statement and including user-supplied values that way. (I don't know the details of how that's done in PHP... I certainly *hope* it's possible.)

EDIT: Okay, now you've changed your code, including this:

```
$a1="SELECT  hosteladmissionno,student_name,semester FROM registration 
WHERE mess_type ".$q."' AND  status_flag=1";
```

Where `$q` is retrieved from a text box. Now I assume you really meant the second line to be:

```
WHERE mess_type='".$q."' AND  status_flag=1";
```

But that's still vulnerable to SQL injection attack. Suppose the value of q is:

```
' OR 'x'='x
```

Your SQL statement would then end up as

```
SELECT hosteladmissionno,student_name,semester FROM registration 
WHERE mess_type='' OR 'x'='x' AND  status_flag=1
```

which clearly isn't the logic you're after.

You should use *parameters* for the values, as shown on this [PHP prepared statement page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Jon,Thanks for the reply. Do you have any example so that i can understand it more precisely.

Comment: @Dinzy: Your edited code *is* vulnerable to injection. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats the answer im looking for!! :)

Comment: Hello jon, i have one more doubt. Is it possible to do an insertion in my above Code? In my code: i have provided a text box, so that user enters the values in the text box and then insert the fields into another DB. Fields include Hostel admissionno, student_name and no of days.

Comment: @Dinzy: The link I gave has an example of using a prepared statement for insertion.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Injection attacks occur when you take data from the user and use it in a query without taking steps to prevent it making expected changes to that query.

Since you aren't using any variables at all in that query, you can't be doing that, so it is safe.

See http://bobby-tables.com/ for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

The advice I was given was to use prepared statements. In practice this is easily accomplished using one of the excellent database abstraction layers:

- http://adodb.sourceforge.net/
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: The advice I'm giving may require a change in your application structure. I would advise you to read about prepared statements and then look over various PHP libraries that may help you with implementing this change in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Put this above your mysql_selected_database portion of your script

```
$qtitle = addcslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($cleantitle),'%_');
```

Where $cleantitle is the original value your are retrieving from a form

If you are using forms that is..

Comment: Whoever down voted me, what is your grounds for your decision. My advice is perfectly acceptable when dealing with forms from the user input. They never specifically said if they are using forms it was just assumed..This down vote was unnecessary

Comment: Yeah, sometimes some freak does that. It's happened to me quite a few times. Though, I would not recommend using mysql_real_escape_string(), I would leave a comment like this rather than a vote down.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia (God bless Google):

> SQL injection is a code injection
>   technique that exploits a security
>   vulnerability occurring in the
>   database layer of an application. The
>   vulnerability is present when user
>   input is either incorrectly filtered
>   for string literal escape characters
>   embedded in SQL statements or user
>   input is not strongly typed and
>   thereby unexpectedly executed. It is
>   an instance of a more general class of
>   vulnerabilities that can occur
>   whenever one programming or scripting
>   language is embedded inside another.
>   SQL injection attacks are also known
>   as SQL insertion attacks.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

though your Query is safe enough, but if u still suspicious then do type casting  `(int)`(php way) or `CAST`(mysql way) with the field name which is integer type in your table and so on..